# Message passing in Elixir

Tags: functional-programming, elixir, erlang-otp

Recently I have started learning Elixir but I struggle a little bit on the implementation part.
I think I did understand the concepts of supervisor and children but I am not so used to functional programming.
Could you give me an example of implementation for such a scenario:

Root Supervisor supervises the processes A and B. B is also a supervisor for some other processes. A should constantly pass messages to B and B should be able to pass these messages to it's children. Also the children of B should be able to pass messages back to B. A and B should be constantly running.

Give me the simplest example of implementation for such scenario, or give me some clues on how to implement the message passing between parent-child, child-child. Take into consideration that I am using mix for the project. Also, A and B should use GenServer

For example, let's suppose inside the root supervisor I have something like this, but now I don't know how to pass message from A to B.

```
    use Supervisor

    def start_link(opts) do
      Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, opts)
    end

    def start(_type, _args) do
        children = [
          {A, [name: NameForA]},
          {B, [name: NameForB]}}
        ]
    
        opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Supervisor]
    
        # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html
        # for other strategies and supported options
    
        Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
    end
```

My assumption is that I should somehow pass to B the PID of A to know where to send the messages, but I don't really know how can I get the PID like this. Maybe I should use another approach?
Any kind of hint or tip is welcomed.

Comment: I recommend you read [Elixir in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/elixir-in-action) by Saša Jurić.

Comment: 1. Is the number of B's children fixed or dynamic?
2. Where's the code where you call B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destination process might be addressed by [`Process.dest()`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html#t:dest/0) type, and names processes exist for exactly this purpose.

In the example above, one might send messages to `NameForA`.

On the other hand, in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) [`Supervisor`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html) behaviour is explicitly dedicated to supervising and not messing with direct message passing. That said, you’d probably need more complicated supervision tree.